# Crystal Report slowness issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have a crystal report in my asp.net website. While users try to fetch 50,000+ records, crystal report is taking 20+ secs to load report. My stored procedure is giving dataset within 6 secs.

Kindly guide me how could I load report faster to user.
Is there any another way or open source reporting tool which could load report faster than Crystal Report.

Let me know, if you require more details to resolve my issue.

After getting feedback from Shakir Ahamed and R. McMillan, I have set to below options, but still facing slowness issue.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P54264
read this article this will be help full to you..

Comment: @ShakirAhamed:  I have opened my rpt file in visual studio 2010, but not able to find Report Option in File menu, which is suggested in shared link's guideline. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Kindly note: I am using SAP Crystal Report

Comment: I believe the menu structure is a bit different in Visual Studio.  Begin in the Crystal Report menu and see if you can find Report Options under one of the sub-menus there.  I would be more specific if I had my laptop with me, but that is the only computer i have VS installed on and its at home today.